# Emacs .el file won't load on startup

Tags: init-file

I'm trying multiple methods to load an emacs `.el` file on startup.

```
('load-file "~/.emacs.d/extra/outline-presentation-mode.el")
```

Also:

```
('load "~/.emacs.d/extra/outline-presentation-mode.el")
```

Also:

```
(mapc 'load (file-expand-wildcards "~/.emacs.d/extra/*.el"))
```

I've also tried adding the extra folder to my path and loading it without the file directory.

If I open emacs and then run:

```
M-x load-file RET ~/.emacs.d/extra/outline-presentation-mode.el
```

It works perfectly.

Why isn't it working when I try the same thing from my `init.el` file? I know the `init.el` file is running because I set my default bindings with `evil-mode` using it.

Also tried:

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/extra/outline-presentation-mode.el")
```

File I'm loading: https://web.archive.org/web/20160810000826/http://clandest.in/emacs.d/plain/outline-presentation.el

Comment: don't quote your function names : `(load "~/path/to/file")`, no apostrophe

Comment: @Tyler thanks but still doesn't seem to work `(load "~/.emacs.d/extra/outline-presentation-mode.el")`

Comment: how does it "not work"? Is there an error message?

Comment: @Tyler there is no error message but when I run `M-x outline-presentation-mode` I get back `[No match]`. If I load manually after opening emacs I am able to use that command.

Comment: Open your init file, and put the cursor after the `load` line. Then press `M-C x` (hold alt and control down and press the x key). Do you get an error message then? Also, check the *Messages* buffer for any errors.

Comment: @Tyler I don't seem to see any errors. I'm assuming that executed the line, I tried running the mode after `M-C x` and I still didn't have access to the command.

Comment: I would use `(load-file "~/.emacs.d/extra/outline-presentation-mode.el")` and suggest you try an init file with *only* that, to eliminate other conflicts (e.g. perhaps Emacs isn't reaching that part of your init file due to other earlier errors).  `load-file` will call `expand-file-name` for you, and tell `load` not to try other suffixes for the file.

Comment: I suggest also starting emacs with the `--debug-init` option, so you'll see a backtrace if an error does occur during init file processing.

Comment: You might also like to verify that `(expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/extra/outline-presentation-mode.el")` gives you the path you're expecting.

Comment: @phils I'm wondering if it relates to the `.el` file itself. It makes use of something called `eval-when-compile`, could that be an issue? File here https://web.archive.org/web/20160810000826/http://clandest.in/emacs.d/plain/outline-presentation.el

Comment: It was because `.emacs.d/init.el` wasn't loading, I changed `.emacs` instead and it worked. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: See `C-h i g (emacs)Find Init`.  Emacs loads only the first init file that it finds.  So you can use `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, but not if you also have a `~/.emacs`